Set Elasticsearch in read-only mode
I'm trying to put my ElasticSearch DB in read only mode, following this page:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/enterprise-search/7.17/read-only-api.html
however when i run the
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200/api/ent/v1/internal/read_only_mode -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u username:password

with the right username and password,i get:
{"error":"no handler found for uri [/api/ent/v1/internal/read_only_mode] and method [GET]"}

any idea on how to solve it?

You're referencing the Enterprise search documentation, which has its own API, on top of the Elasticsearch one.
If you want to make your Elasticsearch server read-only, you can simply run the following command:
curl -X PUT http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -H "Content-Type: application/json" -u username:password -d '{
  "persistent": {
    "cluster.blocks.read_only": true
  }
}'

